# Multiple definitions error in STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: c, linker-errors, stm32cubeide, stm32f7

I have been following along with this documentation for interfacing a digital camera module with an stm32f746g-disco board:

[Link to documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwje5dDc0cD0AhUxknIEHTWlDaEQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fapplication_note%2Fdm00373474-digital-camera-interface-dcmi-on-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01W99UJlvFxSH20qVcY0ZT)

The part I am following specifically is pgs 60-74.

Everything ran fine up until page 68, after completing the steps shown on 68-74 when I compiled I got the following errors:

```
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.6.1\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/Garrett/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.6.2/DCMI_Project/Debug/../Core/Src/font24.c:85: multiple definition of `Font24_Table'; ./Core/Src/font24.o:C:/Users/Garrett/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.6.2/DCMI_Project/Debug/../Core/Src/font24.c:85: first defined here
```

and

```
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.6.1\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:(.data.Font24+0x0): multiple definition of `Font24'; ./Core/Src/font24.o:(.data.Font24+0x0): first defined here
```

and

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:74: DCMI_Project.elf] Error 1
"make -j16 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I am not sure that this is a linker error, as the Font24_Table and Font24 are declared in the header file and defined in the c file.

[Here are the only mentions of the table and font24 in the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajuWw.png)

[This is the definition of the table in the c file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i2wb.png)
and
[This is the definition of the font24 in the c file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQW52.png)

So I tried to debug as a makefile error, and navigated to the makefile. Multiple sources online said that in the C_SRCS I would probably see the same thing twice, and deleting that would solve my problem. However, I do not see anything repeated.

[The makefile I am looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26CbZ.png)

Lastly, I thought I would show the project directory, since there are no visible indicators as to where the error is in the project.

[Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7QMB.png)

Sorry if this question was really dense, I have been troubleshooting this problem for a while now, but I am no expert at C or stm32CubeIDE. I would appreciate any help/input, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\xxx\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_uart.o: in function `HAL_UART_Init': C:/xxx/Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_uart.c:353: multiple definition of` HAL_UART_Init'; ./Core/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_uart.o:C:/xxx/Core/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_uart.c:353: first defined here

"multiple definition of 'HAL_UART_Init'" appears when I compile,

The reason I have this problem is that I did define two "HAL_UART_Init"(I accidentally made a copy of a xxx.c file)

I think your main.c and font24.c maybe all define "Font24_Table" function.

Answer (score 0):

please go through https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html

In STM32CubeIDE, Goto Project Properties->
--> `C/C++ Build`
-->`Settings`
`MCU GCC Compiler`-->
`Miscellaneous`-->
`other flags`
--> Add
`-fcommon`
Apply and Close.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).